# Agregar certificado SSL de un dominio que apunta a noip

Tags: apache, ssl, raspberry-pi, raspbian, letsencrypt

Lo que necesito es configurar SSL en el dominio comprado en una empresa de hosting, supongamos que el dominio comprado es (ejemplo.com) que apunta a mi servidor noip (ejemplo.ddns.net) que ese tiene mi IP pública.

En los DNS del hosting (ejemplo.com) tengo www.ejemplo.com CNAME ejemplo.ddns.net y ese apunta a mi raspberry en este caso, cuando yo entro por ejemplo.com en realidad estoy entrando al del noip, ahora para configurar SSL en el dominio www.ejemplo.com ¿Cómo debería de hacerlo ? Tengo pensado usar letsencrypt

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No queda claro si la empresa del dominio es la misma que la empresa del hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El CNAME es solo redireccionamiento, esto quiere decir que la dirección apunta a otra dirección de ip. Por lo tanto *ejemplo.com* que es el dominio que esta siendo redireccionado no cuenta con ip. Lo que tendrías que hacer es configurar el certificado SSL en dónde esta alojado *ejemplo.ddns.net*

Para encriptar con letsencrypt, Cerbot o algún otro software gratuito de SSL tienes que ingresar a la consola de Linux de tu sevidor a través de SSH e instalar el software como lo muestra en la documentación [Cerbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

Si no tiene acceso a la consola y estas en un Hosting como GoDaddy tienes que pagar ya que no te permiten hacer estas modificaciones. Puedes revisar la [lista](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/web-hosting-who-support-lets-encrypt/6920) de proveedores que te dejan instalar letsencrypt sin acceder a la consola.